# I bought it from the store or market

Tags: word-usage

Some asked if the cocoa in the chocolate was ethically sourced. So the other person gets irritated and says:

> I don't know I got it from the store!

> I don't know I got it from the market!

Does "market" sound fine here? Or is it unlikely to be used?

Answer (score 2):

They would use "market" if they got it from the market, but a "shop"/"store" and "market" are two different things.

A **shop** (or, primarily in American English, **store**) is usually run by a single seller or company (although occasionally one or two others may share the space) and is usually separated from other shops or stores by walls or windows.  A shop may occupy its own building on a town street or it may be part of a shopping centre or shopping mall, a larger building.

A **market** is a place where buyers and sellers come together.  It is often open-air or sheltered (but can also be indoors in a large hall or the like) and usually involves a variety of different sellers who share the space and have tables or stalls next to one another.

Confusingly, the term **supermarket** refers to a large shop selling food, drink and often a range of other items - it doesn't mean a large market.